# Find number in comma separated string SQL

Tags: sql

I have a string which has comma separated number, i am trying to check whether a number exists in it or not. This is the code:

```
Declare @a varchar(10)='0'
Declare @b varchar(10)='1,2,3'
If(CHARINDEX(@a,@b))
Print 'a'
```

The fault of this code is if there will a number '10' in string @b it is returning true.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: if you append comma at the beginning and end of your @b string, you can check your value as `,value,` to avoid 0 being found in 10. If you need a stronger function, you'll need to split your comma separated string and compare each value

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name From the syntax, It is SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` operator

```
Declare @a varchar(10)='0'
Declare @b varchar(10)='1,2,3'

if exists (select 1 where ',' + @b + ',' like '%,' + @a + ',%')
print 'exist'
else 
print 'does not exist'
```

Catch here is appending comma before and after to source and search string

Answer (score 0):

or

```
Declare @a varchar(10)='0'
Declare @b varchar(10)='1,2,3'
If(CHARINDEX(','+@a+',',','+@b+','))>0
Print 'a'
```